# Insert data in to Progress db through PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, progress-db

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver][20101]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "'BatchStatus','BatchRecepient','" (10713), SQL state 60

I'm using the below code to insert data in to Progress db:

```
INSERT INTO PUB.WebReportBatch ('BatchStatus','BatchRecepient','OrderNumber','BatchPartner') 
VALUES ('Pending','dfg@sd.vom','00003660','')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'BatchStatus', 'BatchRecepient', 'OrderNumber', 'BatchPartner' are values. You might want to change that statement to something like this:

insert into PUB.WebReportBatch (BatchStatus,BatchRecepient,OrderNumber,BatchPartner) values ('Pending','dfg@sd.vom','00003660','')

Answer (score 1):

Note: Never use the single quotes when you write the column name inside the insert query. So the query will be -

```
INSERT INTO PUB.WebReportBatch (BatchStatus,BatchRecepient,OrderNumber,BatchPartner) VALUES ('Pending','dfg@sd.vom','00003660','')
```